How infopackage for extraction delta keeps track of what it did?
If you create an infopackage that extracts full but with date period condition, is it going to change something in what infopackage that extracts delta does?
I have missing data from a year ago and i would rather not pull full table since its a 100mil or so rows....so how to create infopackage that pulls just the missing dates worth of data?
Is a large table and i think it would be a hard for system to process that much data with everything else it has to do. Missing data can be delt with deleting PSA and reinitialize delta and full but maybe there is another way.. I hope

I found that table ROOSGENDLM holds delta pointers for my datasource. How can i change dates of those pointers? I could pull as much as 20 times less data that way....and not change anything in process chain
